# How to use jQuery to check whether the first letter of a label element is a * and if it is, change it"s colour?

Tags: jquery, string, colors

Basically I have a series of divs which contains a label and an input element in each one of them. Some of these labels have a "*" to denote a required field. I'd like to create a jQuery function to check all label elements for the "*" and if it finds it, to change its colour to red. I've no idea how I could accomplish this.

What I have at the moment:

```
<label for="ccf_name">* Your Name:</label>
<label for="ccf_name">Your Address:</label>
```

I'd like to change the `<label class="">* Your Name:</label>` to `<label class=""><span class="red">*</span> Your Name:</label>`

Any ideas?

Comment: Unless you are doing this to learn jQuery, it is a much better idea to use a class for this purpose. That way you do not need to use JavaScript at all. That is, add a class named "required-field-label" and add it to all labels that start with *.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it

```
$('label').html(function(idx, currentHtml){
   return currentHtml.replace(/^\*/,'<span class="red">*</span>');
});
```

demo at http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/b5ghj/1/

Answer (score 3):

Select all `label` elements and then filter the selection, with `filter()`, to find those `label`s with a `*` as their first textual character, then use `addClass()` to add the required (pun not intended) class:

```
$('label').filter(
    function() {
        return $(this).text().substring(0, 1) == '*';
    }).addClass('required');​
```

And, in CSS:

```
label.required {
    color: #f00;
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/Lg6Y7/).

References:

- [`addClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/addClass/).
- [`filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/).
- [`substring()` (***not jQuery-specific***)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring).
- [`text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text/).

Comment: ...sigh, I completely missed that requirement. The annoying thing is that I saw, and read, your answer and thought 'goodness, that looks a little complex...I must be missing something' then went to re-read the question and *I still didn't see*... =/

Answer (score 0):

you can get the text using `.text()`

http://api.jquery.com/text/

then use substr() and check and change color usinf

```
.addClass
```

Answer (score 0):

Here I created one way you could do it:

http://jsfiddle.net/Hqwad/